# Fill DIV inbetween header and footer, but no more

Tags: html, css

How can I have a header and footer, with a MainContent div inbetween that fills up all availablel area but never stretches outside of footer or header?

So in other words, fill remaining space inbetween header and footer, but never use any more space?

[image]

I cannot think of how I could do this. I have tried many attempts but unsuccessful because the middle content div always overflows past the top of footer which I don't want happening. I want the content div to stretch only until the top of footer and that's it.

I did try setting overflow: hidden; but that just stops the scrollbars from appearing, nothing else.

No Javascript allowed.

Comment: Why can't CSS learn from Microsoft's XAML? We should be able to have HorizontalAlignment: Left; HorizontalAlignment: Stretch; or VerticalAlignment: Right; that would be cool.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you can set the bottom attribute to be the height of the footer and set the overflow property to auto to add a scroll bar when necessary, that will prevent it from overflowing.

e.g.,

```
#content {
   position: absolute;
   top: <height of header>px;
   bottom: <height of footer>px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bYdgj/1/

Comment: After I tried the others they did not really work as they supposed to, but I checked your fiddle and it works really well. I can settle for scrollbars only when necessary. Ireally like this approach. Thank you :)

Comment: You can set it `overflow: hidden` as well... but if content goes below the height of the content div there isn't an easy way to see it as a user.

Answer (score 2):

If you position the header and footer absolutely, you then should be able to set height and width for the content div to 100%. Make sure to set position of the content div to relative.

Answer (score 1):

are the header and the footer always supposed to be at that position of the screen?

if yes, then you can use the [position: fixed;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed) property for css. This way you can anchor your header and footer to the window screen.

If they are being covered by the main div, throw a z-index on it and the main content div (make sure the main content has a position attribute and a z-index smaller than the header and footer)

Once you do that, you can throw margins on your main content div to make sure that it stays in between your header/footer

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches:

1. Make header and footer absolute, then give the body a height of 100%
2. If you want to fill the whole page except the header and footer with a color or an image, simply change the body `background-color` or `background-image` to whatever you like and you're done
3. Make the content 100% and place the header and footer `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`
4. Make the header and footer `position: fixed`, but then your header and footer would be in front of body

I would take the 2nd approach, because I can't imagine a situation where you need to fit the content exactly between header and footer.